# ASP.net core return a view() or json/xml based on requested contenttype

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

The [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300616/can-i-use-content-negotiation-to-return-a-view-to-browers-and-json-to-api-calls) is about what I wanted to achieve. In the controllers, all data coming from repos will put into a `ViewModel` object. The requirement is:

```
if (requested content type = "json"){
    return convert-to-json(ViewModel);
else
    return view(ViewModel);
```

However, the suggested solution in [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300616/can-i-use-content-negotiation-to-return-a-view-to-browers-and-json-to-api-calls) (checking `Request.Headers["Accept"].Contains("application/json")`) doesn't look good.

Microsoft's [content negotiation article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting) talks about standard content negotiation (JSON/XML etc...)

I can have a separate WebAPI project, but in this case I cannot justify to write another set of code which just calls repositories and return JSON.

Comment: What do you mean that the solution "doesn't look good"? It looks fine to me.

Comment: You have a solution provided within the framework, but don't like it's appearance? Write a helper method then and "hide" the "ugly" details.

Comment: Content negotiations work when you want to return the same data as part of the response. You want to return two different types based on the condition so content negotiations doesn't handle that.

Comment: @user2058413: Just a question - You linked the article using Formatters - are you saying that is something you _dont_ want to use?

Comment: I'm not the OP, but think I understand the intent of the question. Out-of-the box Content Negotiation doesn't support text/html.  The answer provided on the linked question had the developer add code to the action, which isn't ideal because it has to be repeated in each action, and because it doesn't use the content negotiation feature of ASP.NET.  That said, this is sort of a duplicate, so I posted a new answer to the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Dont try and reinvent the wheel....

Firstly, I do think you should seriously consider using the Content Negogiation 
tactics employed by the ASP Core out of the box (you linked that article about) and use different Formatters, because the framework is using the correct HTTP standard by querying the [Accept headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) for you.

### If you must though...

If you need something else, the solution I think you are after is employing [Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters) to "hide away" the dirty bits you mentioned. You still need to check the contents of the Accept headers MIME Type though, but you can use an attributes based system to do this (If you really dont want to use Formatters).

Here is the simple Attribute. Take note of the `IActionFilter` interface, which asks that we build some functionality into the methods `OnActionExecuted` and `OnActionExecuting`

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class FormatReponseFilterAttribute : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
    private enum FormatResponseType { Json, Xml, Unknown }
    private FormatResponseType _requestedType { get; set; }
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var _result = (ObjectResult)filterContext.Result;
        switch (_requestedType)
        {

            case FormatResponseType.Json:
                var data = new { Data = _result.Value };
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult(data);
                break;
            case FormatResponseType.Xml:
                filterContext.Result = new XmlResult(_result.Value);
                break;
            case FormatResponseType.Unknown:
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Uknown Content Type ain Accept Header");
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        var _contentType = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept"];

        switch (_contentType)
        {
            case string s when (s.Contains("application/json")):
                _requestedType = FormatResponseType.Json;
                break;
            case string e when (e.Contains("/xml")):
                _requestedType = FormatResponseType.Xml;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Unknown Accept Type - dont know how to handle: " + _contentType);
        }
    }
}
```

- `OnActionExecuting` : This runs before an Action method is accessed. This allows us to save away information concerning the Request itself. This is where we check the Headers to see if we have an Accept MIME content type we recognise.
- `OnActionExecuted`  : This method is executed AFTER the Action method from the controller has finished. This queries the `Result` of the context and updates it either using the built in `JsonResult` or using Wallsmedias `XmlResult`. You would need to add more logic here, like checking that Result actually has something before converting etc. You can find the instructions to install and how to use `XmlResult` here:

  https://github.com/Wallsmedia/XmlResult

  You then just decorate your Controller method like so with `FormatResponseFilter`:

  ```
  // GET api/values
  [HttpGet]
  [FormatReponseFilter]
  public IActionResult Get()
  {
      TestModel model = new TestModel { Id = 24, Name = "Gareth" };
      return new ObjectResult(model);
  }
  ```

The last piece to make this work, is to add the XML Formatter into the available Services, within `Startup.cs`:

```
        services.AddMvc()
                .AddXmlFormaterExtensions();
```

Here is a nice [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) showing XML:

[image]

Here is a nice Postman showing the JSON:

[image]

ALso, if you want to play around with the code Ive posted into onto Github here, which includes the Postman Config so you can get up and testing ASAP:

[Source Code](https://github.com/garfbradaz/StackOverFlowAnswers/traee/master/ASP.NET%20MVC/ReturnJSONAndXml/SOAnswer_45164409_3/SOAnswer_45164409_3)

Comment: @user2058413: Let me know if this helps.

Comment: The issue with built-in content negotiation is that it doesn't support text/html out-of-the-box.  Similarly, this code doesn't support text/html or use the view engine.  I think what OP wants is a custom Formatter that uses the built-in view engine.  I answered the referenced question with a similar class that only handles text/html with a ViewResult.  Other requests are then left to built-in content negotiation to handle.